# Ionic App `appRestoredResult` Doesn't Fire

Tags: android, ionic-framework, state, ionic-native

I am building an Ionic app that uses the camera plugin, and I am having problems with getting the data to come back from the camera. As the [Capacitor docs on the Camera plugin](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/camera) (In the paragraph above the [variables section](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/camera#variables)) say, the app will sometimes be "terminated" in the background and so when it returns to the app, you need to listen for the "`appRestoredResult` in the `App` plugin" to get the camera result. The problem that I am having is that this event never seems to fire.

I added listeners for the following events: `backButton`, `pause`, `resume`, `appRestoredResult`, and `appStateChange`.

- `backButton` works, and shows the toast notification (which is what I was using to test to see if the events were fired).
- `pause` seems to only be fired if I press the "home" or "opened apps" button (the ones on the phone, not part of my app).
- `resume` only fires when I return to the app after the `pause` event successfully fired. This event should also fire when I come back from the camera as well, shouldn't it?
- `appRestoredResult` doesn't seem to fire ever. Which it should fire after returning to the app after the camera (if the app was terminated during the picture taking).
- `appStateChange` fires when I `pause` or `resume` the app.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

With a little more digging and a little more testing, I figured out the problem.

The reason why `appRestoredResult` event isn't firing, is because it only works with a specific camera library (which I had switched to previous to see if I could get that to work, but then I started using these events, and didn't switch back).

This is what I had previously

```js
...
import { App } from "@capacitor/app";
import { Camera } from "@ionic-native/camera/ngx";
...
```

This is what I have now

```js
...
import { App } from "@capacitor/app";
import { Camera } from "@capacitor/camera";
...
```

So if you are having trouble with the `appRestoredResult` event not firing, check your libraries and make sure you are using both from `@capacitor`.